# Forbid user to explore Index of/ with Jekyll

Tags: url, http-status-code-404, jekyll

I have a problem which doesnt seem documented at all. When you type a custom url from a Jekyll blog, you can explore the site directory :

http://example.com/category/article (shows the article)
-> If someone enters http://example.com/category/ which is not referenced in Jekyll, he can find this :

[image]

I would like Jekyll (or htaccess i guess) to only display the pages i actually published. Maybe return a custom 404 page to reroute users. The main problem here is the SEO with Google which indexes this kind of content and it's ugly :)

Answer (score 3):

This because you don't have an index.html file in you folder.

#### The Jekyll way

On github pages, you will get a 404 error, not the directory listing.

On another type of host, you can use [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) and make a 404.html page like this :

```
---
layout: default
title: 404 Not Foune
permalink: /404.html
redirect_from:
  - /category/
  - /other/folder/to/protect/
---

<h2>This is a 404 !</h2>
```

This will then create /category/index.html and /other/folder/to/protect/index.html files that redirect to the 404 page.

#### Dealing with apache

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /path/from/root/404.html
```

This is ugly (return a 404 page for a 403 forbiden) but it does the trick.

Comment: Is there no way for Jekyll to detect it because my site has like a lot of different categories pattern ?  (and it will be hard to protect all of them, especially when i use two nested categories on my urls).

Comment: Where are you hosted ?

Comment: OVH, I "glynn" my files on FTP.